# How to integrate svn on PL/SQL developer

Tags: svn, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I want to know if there is any way to integrate svn on PL/SQL Developer.
I know that it can be done with git, but my team is not comfortable using it, so it has to  be done with svn.

Comment: What's wrong with just installing TortoiseSVN on your Windows desktop?

Comment: That it can't be used through the IDE PL/SQL Developer

Comment: File > Open works for me. What do you want PL/SQL Developer to do?

Comment: I want to be able to use Subversion from PL/SQL developer, do check in/out, add files...

Comment: Subversion doesn't really have checkouts though. You can just edit the files you need. Often you check in several related changes at once, and I can't see how any desktop editor could handle that better than simply right-clicking on the source folder and selecting 'SVN Commit'.